# Missing StackExchange web elements in Tor Browser

Tags: support, tor

When accessing StackExchange with Tor Browser certain elements (favorite star, upvote button, downvote buttonn) are missing from the view.

All scripts are enabled in Tor Browser.

What other setting do I need to set to obtain regular StackExchange interface?

Tor Browser (8.5.5):

[image]

Safari:

[image]

Comment: Are you blocking SVGs?

Comment: How much market share does Tor have?  More than IE6?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Tor is based on Firefox, just with stricter standards. This problem can happen with Firefox too, and I actually vaguely remember a similar post about Firefox. But yeah, for the most part, the webkit acts like Firefox.

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you the sock of Will?

Comment: [Possible cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387382/6296561)